# GetJSON from URL into d3.js chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing, d3.js

I am trying to load a json into my d3.js chart. I tried at first with a statics hard-coded dummy json (freqData) which works fine but when I try to reproduce the json from a URL (freqData2), the chart is not created as it cannot read my json. I see no differences in structure or variable names.

You can take a look at this jsfiddle (don't pay attention to the chart itself, it's a little messy in my jsfiddle but in my real code it works correctly with proper data). https://jsfiddle.net/liostse/yfw3zgdL/2/

```
function dashboard(id, fData) { /*Creating dashboard for priorities*/
  var barColor = 'steelblue';

  function segColor(c) {
    return {
      P2: "#807dba",
      P3: "#e08214",
      P4: "#41ab5d",
      P5: "#1dc609",
      P6: "#f7f322"
    }[c];
  }
  // compute total for each state.
  fData.forEach(function(d) {
    console.log(d.freq.P2);
    d.total = d.freq.P2 + d.freq.P3 + d.freq.P4 + d.freq.P5 + d.freq.P6;
    console.log(d.total);
  });
  // function to handle histogram.
  function histoGram(fD) {
    var hG = {},
      hGDim = {
        t: 30,
        r: 30,
        b: 20,
        l: 50
      };
    hGDim.w = 600 - hGDim.l - hGDim.r,
      hGDim.h = 300 - hGDim.t - hGDim.b;
    //create svg for histogram.
    var hGsvg = d3.select(id).append("svg")
      .attr("width", hGDim.w + hGDim.l + hGDim.r)
      .attr("height", hGDim.h + hGDim.t + hGDim.b).append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + hGDim.l + "," + hGDim.t + ")");
    // create function for x-axis mapping.
    var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, hGDim.w], 0.1)
      .domain(fD.map(function(d) {
        return d[0];
      }));
    // Add x-axis to the histogram svg.
    hGsvg.append("g").attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + hGDim.h + ")")
      .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"));
    // Create function for y-axis map.
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([hGDim.h, 0])
      .domain([0, d3.max(fD, function(d) {
        return d[1];
      })]);
    // Create bars for histogram to contain rectangles and freq labels.
    var bars = hGsvg.selectAll(".bar").data(fD).enter()
      .append("g").attr("class", "bar");
    //create the rectangles.
    bars.append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d[0]);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d[1]);
      })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return hGDim.h - y(d[1]);
      })
      .attr('fill', barColor)
      .on("mouseover", mouseover) // mouseover is defined below.
      .on("mouseout", mouseout); // mouseout is defined below.
    //Create the frequency labels above the rectangles.
    bars.append("text").text(function(d) {
        return d3.format(",")(d[1])
      })
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d[0]) + x.rangeBand() / 2;
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d[1]) - 5;
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle");

    function mouseover(d) { // utility function to be called on mouseover.
      // filter for selected state.
      var st = fData.filter(function(s) {
          return s.State == d[0];
        })[0],
        nD = d3.keys(st.freq).map(function(s) {
          return {
            type: s,
            freq: st.freq[s]
          };
        });
      // call update functions of pie-chart and legend.    
      pC.update(nD);
      leg.update(nD);
    }

    function mouseout(d) { // utility function to be called on mouseout.
      // reset the pie-chart and legend.    
      pC.update(tF);
      leg.update(tF);
    }
    // create function to update the bars. This will be used by pie-chart.
    hG.update = function(nD, color) {
      // update the domain of the y-axis map to reflect change in frequencies.
      y.domain([0, d3.max(nD, function(d) {
        return d[1];
      })]);
      // Attach the new data to the bars.
      var bars = hGsvg.selectAll(".bar").data(nD);
      // transition the height and color of rectangles.
      bars.select("rect").transition().duration(500)
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return y(d[1]);
        })
        .attr("height", function(d) {
          return hGDim.h - y(d[1]);
        })
        .attr("fill", color);
      // transition the frequency labels location and change value.
      bars.select("text").transition().duration(500)
        .text(function(d) {
          return d3.format(",")(d[1])
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return y(d[1]) - 5;
        });
    }
    return hG;
  }
  // function to handle pieChart.
  function pieChart(pD) {
    var pC = {},
      pieDim = {
        w: 250,
        h: 250
      };
    pieDim.r = Math.min(pieDim.w, pieDim.h) / 2;
    // create svg for pie chart.
    var piesvg = d3.select(id).append("svg")
      .attr("width", pieDim.w).attr("height", pieDim.h).append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + pieDim.w / 2 + "," + pieDim.h / 2 + ")");
    // create function to draw the arcs of the pie slices.
    var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(pieDim.r - 10).innerRadius(0);
    // create a function to compute the pie slice angles.
    var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).value(function(d) {
      return d.freq;
    });
    // Draw the pie slices.
    piesvg.selectAll("path").data(pie(pD)).enter().append("path").attr("d", arc)
      .each(function(d) {
        this._current = d;
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return segColor(d.data.type);
      })
      .on("mouseover", mouseover).on("mouseout", mouseout);
    // create function to update pie-chart. This will be used by histogram.
    pC.update = function(nD) {
      piesvg.selectAll("path").data(pie(nD)).transition().duration(500)
        .attrTween("d", arcTween);
    }
    // Utility function to be called on mouseover a pie slice.
    function mouseover(d) {
      // call the update function of histogram with new data.
      hG.update(fData.map(function(v) {
        return [v.measure_code, v.freq[d.data.type]];
      }), segColor(d.data.type));
    }
    //Utility function to be called on mouseout a pie slice.
    function mouseout(d) {
      // call the update function of histogram with all data.
      hG.update(fData.map(function(v) {
        return [v.measure_code, v.total];
      }), barColor);
    }
    // Animating the pie-slice requiring a custom function which specifies
    // how the intermediate paths should be drawn.
    function arcTween(a) {
      var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
      this._current = i(0);
      return function(t) {
        return arc(i(t));
      };
    }
    return pC;
  }
  // function to handle legend.
  function legend(lD) {
    var leg = {};
    // create table for legend.
    var legend = d3.select(id).append("table").attr('class', 'legend');
    // create one row per segment.
    var tr = legend.append("tbody").selectAll("tr").data(lD).enter().append("tr");
    // create the first column for each segment.
    tr.append("td").append("svg").attr("width", '16').attr("height", '16').append("rect")
      .attr("width", '16').attr("height", '16')
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return segColor(d.type);
      });
    // create the second column for each segment.
    tr.append("td").text(function(d) {
      return d.type;
    });
    // create the third column for each segment.
    tr.append("td").attr("class", 'legendFreq')
      .text(function(d) {
        return d3.format(",")(d.freq);
      });
    // create the fourth column for each segment.
    tr.append("td").attr("class", 'legendPerc')
      .text(function(d) {
        return getLegend(d, lD);
      });
    // Utility function to be used to update the legend.
    leg.update = function(nD) {
      // update the data attached to the row elements.
      var l = legend.select("tbody").selectAll("tr").data(nD);
      // update the frequencies.
      l.select(".legendFreq").text(function(d) {
        return d3.format(",")(d.freq);
      });
      // update the percentage column.
      l.select(".legendPerc").text(function(d) {
        return getLegend(d, nD);
      });
    }

    function getLegend(d, aD) { // Utility function to compute percentage.
      return d3.format("%")(d.freq / d3.sum(aD.map(function(v) {
        return v.freq;
      })));
    }
    return leg;
  }
  // calculate total frequency by segment for all state.
  var tF = ['P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6'].map(function(d) {
    return {
      type: d,
      freq: d3.sum(fData.map(function(t) {
        return t.freq[d];
      }))
    };
  });
  // calculate total frequency by state for all segment.
  var sF = fData.map(function(d) {
    return [d.measuer_code, d.total];
  });
  var hG = histoGram(sF), // create the histogram.
    pC = pieChart(tF), // create the pie-chart.
    leg = legend(tF); // create the legend.
}
freqData2 = [];
$.getJSON('http://88.99.13.199:3000/dashboarddata', function(mydata) {
  mydata.forEach(function(val) {
    var freqData1 = {};
    freqData1["measure_code"] = val.measure_code;
    freqData1["freq"] = {
      P2: val.p2,
      P3: val.p3,
      P4: val.p4,
      P5: val.p5,
      P6: val.p6
    };
    freqData2.push(freqData1);
  });
  return freqData2;
});
var freqData = [{
  measure_code: 'Μ1',
  freq: {
    P2: 47,
    P3: 19,
    P4: 29,
    P5: 20,
    P6: 100
  }
}, {
  measure_code: 'Μ2',
  freq: {
    P2: 11,
    P3: 42,
    P4: 74,
    P5: 15,
    P6: 10
  }
}, {
  measure_code: 'Μ3',
  freq: {
    P2: 93,
    P3: 21,
    P4: 48,
    P5: 10,
    P6: 10
  }
}, {
  measure_code: 'Μ4',
  freq: {
    P2: 82,
    P3: 11,
    P4: 12,
    P5: 50,
    P6: 20
  }
}, {
  measure_code: 'Μ5',
  freq: {
    P2: 44,
    P3: 34,
    P4: 98,
    P5: 10,
    P6: 14
  }
}, {
  measure_code: 'Μ6',
  freq: {
    P2: 19,
    P3: 17,
    P4: 13,
    P5: 10,
    P6: 10
  }
}, {
  measure_code: 'Μ7',
  freq: {
    P2: 18,
    P3: 27,
    P4: 12,
    P5: 50,
    P6: 18
  }
}, {
  measure_code: 'Μ8',
  freq: {
    P2: 48,
    P3: 38,
    P4: 42,
    P5: 15,
    P6: 17
  }
}, {
  measure_code: 'Μ9',
  freq: {
    P2: 77,
    P3: 18,
    P4: 15,
    P5: 50,
    P6: 14
  }
}, {
  measure_code: 'Μ10',
  freq: {
    P2: 162,
    P3: 39,
    P4: 41,
    P5: 40,
    P6: 10
  }
}, {
  measure_code: 'Μ11',
  freq: {
    P2: 62,
    P3: 39,
    P4: 41,
    P5: 15,
    P6: 20
  }
}, {
  measure_code: 'Μ12',
  freq: {
    P2: 12,
    P3: 39,
    P4: 41,
    P5: 15,
    P6: 12
  }
}, {
  measure_code: 'Μ13',
  freq: {
    P2: 162,
    P3: 39,
    P4: 71,
    P5: 30,
    P6: 10
  }
}, {
  measure_code: 'Μ14',
  freq: {
    P2: 62,
    P3: 79,
    P4: 41,
    P5: 15,
    P6: 12
  }
}, {
  measure_code: 'Μ16',
  freq: {
    P2: 12,
    P3: 39,
    P4: 41,
    P5: 10,
    P6: 10
  }
}, {
  measure_code: 'Μ19',
  freq: {
    P2: 16,
    P3: 379,
    P4: 41,
    P5: 10,
    P6: 10
  }
}, {
  measure_code: 'Μ20',
  freq: {
    P2: 16,
    P3: 39,
    P4: 41,
    P5: 50,
    P6: 32
  }
}, {
  measure_code: 'Μ97',
  freq: {
    P2: 62,
    P3: 379,
    P4: 47,
    P5: 50,
    P6: 10
  }
}];
console.log(typeof freqData2);
console.log(typeof freqData2);
dashboard('#dashboard', freqData);
```

Any help would be wonderful!

Comment: There is the [`json()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/blob/master/README.md#json) method in the D3 library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see the problem with the $.getJSON method, you are trying to load the data from HTTP so you might be getting the mixed content error in jsfiddle console, but try to run it from local machine using http server, you will get the data.

Comment: Is there any difference between freqData and freqData2?

Comment: no I think its same, but that you are getting using ajax call, so you need to execute the dashboard func inside the callback ->

Comment: d3.json('http://88.99.13.199:3000/dashboarddata', function(err, mydata) {
  mydata.forEach(function(val) {
    var freqData1 = {};
    freqData1["measure_code"] = val.measure_code;
    freqData1["freq"] = {
      P2: val.p2,
      P3: val.p3,
      P4: val.p4,
      P5: val.p5,
      P6: val.p6
    };

    freqData2.push(freqData1);
  });

  // call dashboard here
});

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine but you have a few problems.

Here is the code that will work.

See the comments to know what you did wrong.

```
var freqData2 = []; //You didn't declared a var

//Use d3.json instead of jquery.getJSON
//As also suggested by @Alexandra in the comments
d3.json('http://88.99.13.199:3000/dashboarddata', function(err, mydata) {

 console.log(err);

 if(mydata && mydata.length > 0) {
 //if mydata is defined and have data then loop

 mydata.forEach(function(val) {
    var freqData1 = {};
    freqData1["measure_code"] = val.measure_code;
    freqData1["freq"] = {
      P2: val.p2,
      P3: val.p3,
      P4: val.p4,
      P5: val.p5,
      P6: val.p6
    };

    freqData2.push(freqData1);
  });
}  
  return freqData2;
});

//Timeout? WHY? because it takes time for url to respond back 
//and then all that data manipulation on it. 
//So, we will wait 1 Second to get data back and then we will print it.

setTimeout(()=>{
dashboard('#dashboard', freqData2);
},1000);
```

Other issue was that you were getting mixed content error in JSfiddle. Why? because you were trying to get data from HTTP where as JSFiddle by default goes to HTTPS.